# How can i break H1 Title if screen is to small

Tags: html, css

I want to make my site responsive.
i already fixe the divs and Paragraph tags.

i tried things like break word and white space but didnt work.

the Paragraph tags automaticly go next line if screen is smaller. but i cant get H1 to do that.

I will add my html code below and add a link for screenshot and css code.

Mobile Size: https://gyazo.com/dd12083cba1261160d945cc64cb57ad7
Jfiddle (Html Css): https://jsfiddle.net/ofdtedtx/

```
        <div class="content">
          <div class="article">
            <h1>Introductie</h1>
            <p>Informatie over de site en toegepaste kennis:</p><br>
            <div class="infobox">
                <h1>Html 5</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Standaard Toepassingen</li>
                        <li>Forms</li>
                        <li>Input Types</li>
                        <li>Divs</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `.article h1` , give it a `line-height:1`, should work.

```
.article h1 {
    color: #4e4e4e;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    font-size: 4rem;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should increase the line-height and put word-wrap in CSS

```
.article h1 {
    color: #4e4e4e;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 4rem;
    line-height: 1;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ofdtedtx/3/)